# Laravel Route not working properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this function in the laravel controller

```
public function rawquery()
{ 
     $resultado = DB::statement('SELECT * FROM "w8_w8shipment"');
     dd($resultado);
     return response()->json($resultado);
}
```

And this is the route to get access to it

```
Route::get('shipment/rawquery', 'ShipmentController@rawquery');
```

In the browser and postman, it shows an empty object

```
{}
```

And a `200 OK` code

I don't know what's wrong. i've already read the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Ive already check that.  I change it like this ->   $resultado = DB::statement("SELECT * FROM 'w8_w8shipment' ");  and its not working either. @aynber

Comment: That's because it's still incorrect. Reread the duplicate: column names and table names should be surrounded by backticks, not single or double quotes. `'SELECT * FROM \`w8_w8shipment\`'`

Comment: I didnt notice that... But I corrected it, and still not working :( 
Now I have it like this    $resultado = DB::statement("SELECT * FROM `w8_w8shipment`");  @aynber

Comment: Try this instead: `$resultado = DB::table('w8_w8shipment')->get();`  If that doesn't work, there's no data in that table.

Comment: Its weird because its a table with a lot of data and im sure of that. i hope you can help @aynber

Comment: can you send GET request while `dd` function there ? and see the response ?

Answer (score 0):

***Try using this function***

```
public function rawQuery()
{
         $data = 'SELECT * FROM "w8_w8shipment"';

         $resultado = DB::select(DB::raw($data));

         return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $resultado], '200');
}
```